# How can I add scaling factors to my "perlin" noise generator?

Tags: c#, terrain, perlin-noise

I have a Perlin noise generator which I am attempting to use to create scrolling terrain.

I've got a center terrain, eight terrains of the same side surrounding it (these are working fine) and a second ring of terrains which are three times larger. For these, I need my noise generator to output noise that is three times "denser", such that I could place a larger terrain over a smaller terrain and, except for the three times larger tiles (and map size), they'd match.

I don't want to just generate a larger map; that would quickly get prohibitive.

I do not know what to do; the obvious solutions all failed, one way or another.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a new perlin map.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xStart">The left coordinate (using 0, 0 as top-left and +, + as down and to the right).</param>
    /// <param name="yStart">The top coordinate (using 0, 0 as top-left and +, + as down and to the right).</param>
    /// <param name="width">The width of the map.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The length of the map.</param>
    /// <param name="persistance">If set, values lower than 1 make the map less noisey; values greater than 1 make the map more noisy.</param>
    /// <param name="fromShift">Low values here provide for a broader "base".</param>
    /// <param name="toShift">High values here provide for more speckled "highlights".</param>
    /// <param name="interpolate">If set to false, the algorithm will not smooth values.</param>
    public double[,] Generate(
        int xStart, int yStart,
        int width, int length,
        double? persistance,
        uint fromShift, uint toShift,
        bool interpolate = true,
    )
    {
        _noiseMap = new double[width, length];
        _workingMap = new double[width + 6, length + 6];
        _smoothedNoise = new double[width + 6, length + 6];
        int ifromShift = -(int)(toShift),
            itoShift = -(int)(fromShift);
        int idiv = 1 + (itoShift - ifromShift);
        double ddiv = 0;
        double amplitude = 0.0;
        if (persistance.HasValue)
            for (int i = ifromShift; i <= itoShift; ++i)
                ddiv += Math.Pow(persistance.Value, i);

        for (int i = ifromShift; i <= itoShift; ++i)
        {
            _frequency = Math.Pow(2, i);
            if (persistance.HasValue) amplitude = Math.Pow(persistance.Value, i);
            int useWidth = (int)(width * _frequency) + 1,
                useLength = (int)(length * _frequency) + 1;
            int useXStart = (int)(xStart * _frequency),
                useYStart = (int)(yStart * _frequency);
            double frequencyXStart = xStart * _frequency - useXStart,
                frequencyYStart = yStart * _frequency - useYStart;

            for (int y = 0; y < useLength + 5; ++y)
                for (int x = 0; x < useWidth + 5; ++x)
                {
                    int genX = ((int)(useXStart) + (int)((x) + 0.5));
                    int genY = ((int)(useYStart) + (int)((y) + 0.5));
                    _workingMap[x, y] = GenerateNoise(genX, genY);
                }

            if (interpolate)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < length + 4; ++y)
                    for (int x = 1; x < width + 4; ++x)
                    {
                        _smoothedNoise[x, y] = SmoothedNoise(x, y);
                    }

                if (persistance.HasValue)
                    for (int y = 0; y < length; ++y)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                        {
                            _noiseMap[x, y] += InterpolatedNoise((x * _frequency) + 2 + frequencyXStart, (y * _frequency) + 2 + frequencyYStart) * amplitude;
                            // _noiseMap[x, y] += _workingMap[x, y] * amplitude;
                        }
                else
                    for (int y = 0; y < length; ++y)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                        {
                            _noiseMap[x, y] += InterpolatedNoise((x * _frequency) + 2 + frequencyXStart, (y * _frequency) + 2 + frequencyYStart) / idiv;
                            // _noiseMap[x, y] += _workingMap[x, y] / idiv;
                        }
            }
            else
                if (persistance.HasValue)
                    for (int y = 0; y < length; ++y)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                        {
                            _noiseMap[x, y] +=
                                _workingMap[(int)((x * _frequency) + 2 + frequencyXStart), (int)((y * _frequency) + 2 + frequencyYStart)] * amplitude;
                        }
                else
                    for (int y = 0; y < length; ++y)
                        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                        {
                            _noiseMap[x, y] +=
                                _workingMap[(int)((x * _frequency) + 2 + frequencyXStart), (int)((y * _frequency) + 2 + frequencyYStart)] / idiv;
                        }
        }

        if (persistance.HasValue)
            for (int y = 0; y < length; ++y)
                for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                {
                    _noiseMap[x, y] = _noiseMap[x, y] / ddiv;
                }

        return _noiseMap;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Denser data = more data for the same space.  Generating "larger" maps and scaling them sounds like the only possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear (to check my understanding of your problem).

You generate a map A with side of size X.
This map is surrounded by nine more maps B1...B9, each with side of size X.
Now you want maps C1...C2, which will surround maps B1...B9 from the outside. Each of these maps will have a side of size 3X, but with only X^2 data points (each data point will be of size 3x3).

Right?

Have you tried just interpolating the data with nearest neighbor algorithm? When any code asks for a data from coordinate X, just round the coordinate to a multiple of three and use it. I think this should work.

Another option would be to use the [midpoint displacement algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm), except you would split the tile into three parts instead of just two in each recursive step. This would allow you to stop one round early, which would present you with the result you are looking for: A height map with data points generated only on intersection points of 3x3 grid. Without ever having to touch the remaining points.

Comment: Entirely correct. There's a few problems with those ideas, though. The problem with the first idea is that I'd end up accessing values outside of the array. The problem with the second is, first, making the displacement consistent, second, not ending up with a larger array and third, potentially prohibitive cost in time.

Comment: I still didn't understand the question, if you keep the data from the low resolution version, and then just sample some more points, 2 in between every low resolution point then you will have 3 times denser data. consider queueing the chunks so they all render in order in sequence with a couple of frames of delay each one.

Answer (score 0):

Perlin noise is alot more dense than your samples can be, so the shape of one algorythm is dense for all grids. if you want extra detail, you have to add an octave or a second pass of noise, in which case the grids wouldnt overlay properly. so it's a question of choosing a shape and sampling it with different grid densities.